# Two has_may association with Same model Rail 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-many

Hi im quite beginner in rails. i have a problem suggestion will be appreciated.
i have two model "user" and "asset"
an "asset" is created by a "user" and asset" can be assigned to a "user" schema is

```
Asset { id,name,creator_id,assigned_to_id,price,...}

User{ id,name,....}
```

now in Asset model class association are

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
{
 #validation
belongs_to :creator ,:class_name=>'User'
belongs_to :assigned_to, :class_name=>'User' ,:foreign_key=>'assigned_to_id'
}
```

and User Model is

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
{
#any validation and other stuff
has_many :assets #did not specify either this association  is for creator , or   assigned_to  user.how can is specify that??
}
```

now in Asset show view i can obtain creator name with

```
@asset.creator.name
```

but can't assigned_to name

```
@asset.assigned_to.name =>(error is )undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClas
```

and
    @asset.assigned_to_id.name=>(error is) undefined method `first_name' for 1:Fixnum

any suggestion how can i make double association with same model

Comment: after reading [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149128/rails-3-multiple-has-one-associations-seeding) i have changed my User model  class User<ActiveRecord::Base{ has_many :created_assets, :foreign_key => 'creator_id', :class_name => 'Asset'
  has_many :assigned_assets , :foreign_key => 'assigned_to_id', :class_name => 'Asset'
  } and asset model is unchanged now it worked well in console output of console is u=User.new :first_name=>'foo' u.id=12   u.inspect=>"#<User id: 34,first_name:foo> also u2.inspect=>"#<User id: 45,first_name:bar> ...more on next comment

Comment: now lets create Asset irb(main):032:0> asset=Asset.new :assigned_to_id=>u,:creator_id=>u2,:name=>'Android'
=> #<Asset id: nil, name: "Android", assigned_to_id: 1, creator_id: 1> now 
 asset.assigned_to.name=>(error)  undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass and same error for asset.creator.first_name   but if i assign after declaring asset like a.assigned_to=u ,a.creator=u2 now a.assigned_to.first_name=>'bar'  and a.creator.first_name=>'foo'   {interesting} but these all is for console.in views only asset.creator.first_name works plz any suggestion im stuck here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok solution was in my last comment. 
[Multiple relation with same model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391964/multiple-relation-with-same-model)

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :creator ,:class_name=>'User'
belongs_to :assigned_to, :class_name=>'User' 

end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :created_assets, :foreign_key => 'creator_id', :class_name => 'Asset'
has_many :assigned_assets , :foreign_key => 'assigned_to_id', :class_name => 'Asset'

end
```